# Swift unable to get callback

Tags: ios, swift

I added a comment box to one of my viewcontroller like

```
private lazy var toolbarView: KeyboardToolbar = {
    guard let keyboardToolbar = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KeyboardToolbar", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? KeyboardToolbar else {
        fatalError("Error") 
    }
    return keyboardToolbar
}()
override var inputAccessoryView: KeyboardToolbar? {
    return toolbarView
}
```

Now in the keyboard toolbar's swift file i have

```
@IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //called on click of send button in the comment box
}
```

How can I write a function in viewcontroller code that gets executed on sendPressed in comment box .

Full KeyboardToolbar code

```
class KeyboardToolbar: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    textView.delegate = self
    autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.text = "Comment"
    textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let textSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: textSize.height)
}
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}

@IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}
}
```

Comment: Show your `KeyboardToolBar`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri added

Comment: Use protocol , check this [link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

Comment: The `sendPressed()` method belongs in your view controller, not your view (view controllers control views and manage models).  Set the target of the send button to be the view controller, and establish this relationship when the view controller instantiates the view.  Because your `toolbarView` is `lazy`, the view controller's `self` is available at the time it is created, so you can setup this relationship in the `toolbarView` creation closure.  There is no need for a protocol here and really it's the wrong pattern to use in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a custom protocol for you `KeyboardToolBar`

```
protocol KeyboardToolBarDelegates: class {
    func sendPressed(_ text: String)
}
```

Now you can create delegate object in your KeyboardToolBar

```
class KeyboardToolbar: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {
     @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
     weak var delegate: KeyboardToolBarDelegates?

     @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.sendPressed("Pass your text")
     }

}
```

Implement Delegate in your viewcontroller :

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController, KeyboardToolBarDelegates {
   private lazy var toolbarView: KeyboardToolbar = {
       guard let keyboardToolbar = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KeyboardToolbar", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? KeyboardToolbar else {
          fatalError("Error") 
       }
       keyboardToolbar.delegate = self
       return keyboardToolbar
   }()
   override var inputAccessoryView: KeyboardToolbar? {
      return toolbarView
   }

   //Add protocol method
   func sendPressed(_ text: String) {
       //Method will be called when send pressed from the KeyboardToolBar
   }
}
```

Comment: delegate should be weak var.

Comment: i had to do protocol KeyboardToolBarDelegates: class {  how can I pass a text param in the function too?

Comment: For future user's reference, protocol should be `protocol KeyboardToolBarDelegates: class { }`. Protocol method param should have an underscore `func sendPressed(_ text: String)` too if you're using it this way `delegate?.sendPressed("Pass your text")` @sohanvanani

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions let me update answer @Sean

Comment: See my comment on the question.  This is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Sean to which naming conventions are you referring to in your comment?